# HTML Element Object vs Object

Tags: javascript, html, object, dictionary

Can anyone please help me why I couldn't get the right result for this code?

```
    Javascript:
    var items2 = $("#quadrant1");
    var coords = items2.getAttribute('coords').split(',');

    HTML:
    <map id="square_map" name="square">
        <area id="quadrant1" shape="poly" coords="206,10, 300,10, 388,10"></area>
    </map>
```

I've checked the typeof of items2 and it's just OBJECT, and doesn't appear to get the right HTML AREA OBJECT. All I'm after is to get the element object so I can do further manipulations like in the example to get its coords attribute value.

How do I know that it should be [object HTMLAreaObject]? I'm not sure really, but that's the typeof "this" in

```
$('#square_map").bind("click",function(){
var coords = this.getAttribute('coords').split(',');
... });
```

and it's doing its job properly with that said object. Any help would be appreciated...a lot! Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this have anything to do with your missing a quote after the list of `coords`?

Comment: Ah, no. Just a typo when I copy pasted. The problem's with the DOM/Jquery object after all. If I could vote up the answers below, I would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because items2 is not DOM Element but jQuery object in your example. Right variant:

```
var items2 = $("#quadrant1");
var coords = items2.attr('coords').split(',');
```

or

```
var items2 = $("#quadrant1");
var coords = items2[0].getAttribute('coords').split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the original DOM Object use `$('#quadrant1').get()`. To implement its functionality `jQuery` uses it's own Objects, but always you can get a reference to the original DOM Object, as I mentioned above.